# How to freeze last column in a DataTable in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need some package or workaround to freeze the last column of a DataTable. I have searched and most of the packages froze only the firsts columns, and when I put two data tables and there is not much information it looks broken.

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score -3):

There isn't a specific package or workaround available for freezing the last column of a Data Table in Flutter or Dart. However, you can achieve this functionality by using a combination of widgets and some custom coding.

Here's an example of how you can freeze the last column of a Data Table:

1. Import the necessary packages:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scrollable_positioned_list/scrollable_positioned_list.dart';
```

2. Create a frozen column Data Table widget:

```dart
class FrozenDataTable extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FrozenDataTableState createState() => _FrozenDataTableState();
}

class _FrozenDataTableState extends State<FrozenDataTable> {
  final ItemScrollController itemScrollController = ItemScrollController();
  final ItemPositionsListener itemPositionsListener =
      ItemPositionsListener.create();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(children: [
      // Frozen column
      Container(
        width: 200, // Adjust the width as per your requirement
        child: ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
          itemCount: dataTableSource.rowCount,
          itemScrollController: itemScrollController,
          itemPositionsListener: itemPositionsListener,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => TableRow(
            children: [
              Text(dataTableSource.getName(index)), // Replace with your own data
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      // Scrollable columns
      Expanded(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: DataTable(
            columns: dataTableSource.getColumns(), // Replace with your columns
            rows: dataTableSource.getRows(), // Replace with your rows
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```

In the above code, a FrozenDataTable widget is created which is responsible for freezing the last column of a Data Table. The frozen column is implemented using a ScrollablePositionedList widget, and the scrollable columns are implemented using SingleChildScrollView and DataTable widgets.

3. Define a DataTableSource:

```dart
class DataTableSource {
  // Replace with your own data and column definitions
  final List<String> data = ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3'];
  final List<String> columns = ['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3'];

  int get rowCount => data.length;
  int get columnCount => columns.length;

  String getName(int index) => data[index];

  List<DataColumn> getColumns() {
    return columns.map((String column) => DataColumn(label: Text(column))).toList();
  }

  List<DataRow> getRows() {
    return data.map((String name) {
      return DataRow(cells: [
        DataCell(Text(name)),
        DataCell(Text('Cell2')),
        DataCell(Text('Cell3')),
      ]);
    }).toList();
  }
}
```

In this code, a DataTableSource class is defined, which represents the data source for the Data Table. You can replace the data and column definitions with your own data and column definitions.

4. Use the FrozenDataTable widget in your Flutter app:

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Frozen Data Table')),
        body: FrozenDataTable(), // Use the FrozenDataTable widget here
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In the main.dart file, initialize your app and use the FrozenDataTable widget in the body of the Scaffold.

Remember to import the necessary packages before running the code. The code provided above is a basic implementation, and you may need to customize it further based on your specific requirements.

Note: The code provided is just for reference, and you may need to adjust it as per your project structure and needs.